Function to consider a plugin activated for selected users only
Our WP-based website is maintained by a company that forced the use of Gutenberg upon us, moreover, for some reason, the Classic Editor plugin doesn't work properly on the website probably due to some awful code customizations in the used template - the CE plugin when activated switches the Gutenberg off for all users without any customizable options or switches between the Gutenberg and the classic editor.
Is it possible to make a function that will switch on the Classic Editor plugin only for a handful of selected users?
Something like:
$CE_users = array('user1', 'user2');
if(is_user_logged_in() && in_array($current_user->user_login, $CE_users)){
    //somehow load plugin Classic Editor
    }


yes, this is possible by creating a new function because thank to wordpress function activate_plugin() that can be used to activate the classic editor plugin for specific users
// Define the usernames of the users who should have the Classic Editor 
enabled
$CE_users = array('user1', 'user2');

// Check if the current user is logged in and their username is in the array 
of CE users
if (is_user_logged_in() && in_array($current_user->user_login, $CE_users)) {
// Activate the Classic Editor plugin
activate_plugin('classic-editor/classic-editor.php');
}

Add this code into Your theme functions.php file of your child theme and see it’s working or not
